# Disable maximize button for displayed image window

Tags: opencv

I want to disallow the user from resizing a displayed image window by dragging/clicking the maximize button in window.

For disabling resize by dragging, I use the below code:

```
cv::namedWindow("Frame",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
```

`CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` disables resizing of window by dragging.

However, I the window still shows a maximize button, which let's the user maximize the window to full screen. How can I disable this maximize button?

Comment: forget it, you can't. don't try to bend the highgui interface, it wasn't made for that. if you need more control, use gtk/qt/winforms instead.

Answer (score 0):

in order to do this you need more than just highgui. I would recommend QT.

There are many tutorials for Qt with opencv, including:

http://hxr99.blogspot.co.at/2011/12/opencv-with-qt-c-examples-showing-image.html

In order to enable full screen under Qt, you have to call:

```
QMainWindow::showFullScreen();
```